# In XML how to align two elements (or widgets) to the right w/ Relative Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Lets say you have two buttons side by side under Relative Layout like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

I have tried adding the attribute android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to both and there are major issues. First, if you add it to button 1 (id:arrow_up) and not to button 2 (id:arrow_down), the second button disappears because button 1 moves all the way to the right. Second, if you add it to button 2 and not button 1, then button 2 will be stretched until it reaches all the way to the right side and ignores all and any width values (40dp as in this example). Third, if you add it to both, the result is as described when you have the alightParentRight attribute under button 1 and not button 2.

So how is this done? How to align both buttons to the right, side by side and maintain the proper assigned width values?

Comment: how you want to show these buttond, vertically or horizontally next to each other ?

Comment: horizontally (side by side), not stacked.

Comment: then you can use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation

Comment: I guess I did not provide enough information. There are other elements, and these buttons are on the 7th row (for example). In other words, they also have the attribute android:layout_below="id/someID". With this said, doing a LinearLayout wrapper around the two buttons misplaces the correct positioning of the buttons. Unless you know of a way to position LinearLayout after RelativeLayout with an attribute of some kind? I have been doing work arounds with margin and padding attributes. It just does not seem so clean. Should I change my setup, maybe LinearLayout per row sort of thing?

Comment: If you are comfortable with RelativeLayout then you can use attributes like- android:layout_toLeftOf, android:layout_toRightOf and and some more to place your components, else, you can use LinearLayout per row to show your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2" />
```

Comment: I see how you do it now. So you have to declare the furthest elements in the row first, and then sort of work your way from right to left (not left to right). Another thing to note since I just tried this out is that I can no longer declare button 2 to be android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1" because of a "circular dependency error". This solution worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I would prefer to say that a view can only refer(e.g. layout_toLeftOf) to views above itself but your logic is fine too I guess :)